# Can ORM (Sequelize) help for data validation for stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures, orm, sequelize.js

I am new to Nodejs and Express; trying to learn several concepts little by little.

I have a fairly good sample web app so far which I use SQL Server as my datasource. I have several stored procedures integrated; some are too long and advanced to complete with simple query statements.

I want to migrate to use ORMs because I still don't have good mechanism to dismiss the input parameters sent from web portion and my understanding is that having an ORM will help me do that. I want to do this with ORM (not HTML level) in case my validation logic extends.

Here is my sample code - I have not figured out how to run the parameters userName and password into a model yet. I'd expect the model to reject the parameters which does not qualify before calling the SP. (Am I right?)

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var username;
var password;

const sequelize = new Sequelize('testDB', 'sa', 'test123', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

// How to use sequilize Model for my inputs of SP
// username cannot be null - Max 10 chars
// password cannot be null - Min 10, max 15 chars

var sp = '__sample ' + username + ',' + password;

sequelize.query(sp)
  .then(function(result) {
      console.log('RESULT', result);
  })
  .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What would be the qualifications criteria
Sequelize provides tons of validations
Just search for model validation in sequelize

Comment: Thank you for the comment, could you please provide specifics for my sample code? What I read (and trying to understand) is that model is created with 'define' method which uses a table. So I am a bit confused how I can create a validation model for my SP inputs?